# Background image with a mask and autozoom transformation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, mask, effect

i'm trying to achieve a effect for my website.

In the header i have a bg with a mask on top of the bg, now i wanted to give the bg a autozoom transformation like a slideshow or something, but i can't get it done.

```css
.header {
 display: table;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

}
#bg-primary {
 z-index:-1;
 display: table;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);

}

#mask {
 z-index:2;
 display:table;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url(../img/raster-light.png) repeat center center scroll;
 background-image: url(../img/raster-light.png); 
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<div id="bg-primary">
    <div id="mask">
      
        <header class="header" id="top" name="top">
         <div class="text-vertical-center">
             <h1>Tittle</h1>
             <h3>Solutions that meet new experiences</h3>
             <br>
             <a href="#about" class="btn btn-light btn-lg ">Find Out More</a>
         </div>
    </header>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: check this site please. im trying to done the same effect for the header...
www.sdsol.com